# Switch Mode Power Supply / GPS - Filtering+Shielding

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, filter, gps, emi-filtering, gnss

I'm working on my first RF PCB, for GPS/ GNSS and am particularly concerned about Noise/ Interference. Hopefully someone can shed some light, or point me toward a similar thread?

It's worth noting that I'm here for the learning experience, so don't want to use a pre-packaged GPS module as I have before.

### Noise from the power supply

I plan to use a 1MHz SMPS;
I plan to filter the +ve rail, using a bulk and a smaller cap. I think this should be enough for my digital circuits (ESP32 + Sensors)?
I also plan to connect the SMPS GND to my GND plane using a single point, perhaps through a passive component or just copper?

1. Will these capacitors be enough for my GPS chip too, or should I add a ferrite bead/ something more?
2. Further, is it worth implementing a single point ground from the SMPS, if so, should I just make a copper connection?
3. Finally here, might it be worth considering a Common Mode Choke at the outputs of my SMPS?

[image: SMPS Query_Example]

### Shielding

Further to filtering noise internal to the PCB, I'd like to consider external influences.
I will test with and without a shield, but would it be better to encapsulate the GPS Chip as much as possible, with any de-caps and peripherals inside, or to capture only the SiP itself?

[image: Shielding Question]

Thanks in Advance,

Ben

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't nearly enough information here to make an assessment. Beware that EMC is an extremely in-depth topic, concerning potentially everything within the project, everything connected to it, and how all those components connect. So, complete schematics and layout at a minimum, preferably assembly drawings too. We also need to know what levels you are testing to (CISPR 22? FCC Part 15?), or what your concerns are (just functional, SMPS to GPS interference?).

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your time - I kept my post general *because* EMC is such an in-depth topic. I won't be testing to any specification or standard and am merely concerned with function at an introductory level.
I'm given to understand that a Common Mode Choke is for, as implied, common mode noise, and a Ferrite Bead for differential noise - but does that mean only a choke is suitable here? This is my first foray into EMC control and need a starting point.
I am looking more toward 'best practise' rather than asking for a 'correct' answer.
Once I have a starting point, then I can iterate.

Comment: But that's the thing. You're asking for a book-length answer: the SMPS depends on how it's made internally, how it's connected externally, presence of shielding, testing levels, etc. A brief answer cannot possibly encompass every aspect of such general scope, even just the highest priority ones. The answer I think you were expecting ("good enough", "probably right", more so than "best practices") will probably be along the lines of what you already have, but which one, and how much, requires all these variables to be filled in.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks again - I'm not looking for a book length answer and already said that I'm not looking to address every aspect of EMC. Something along the lines of "*both a Common Mode Choke and a Ferrite Bead have their merits, personally I would look into (X). I have/ haven't seen much benefit using Single Point Grounding, so try/ leave it*" would have been enough.
I'd appreciate any experience you have to offer, or a reference you've found useful, but if you're going to provide obstructive responses I'll ask that you move to the next post.

Comment: All I really want to convince you of, and others generally, is that there is more -- far more than you can imagine right now -- that matters here. It's a multivariable problem, you're asking about just one of them in the hopes that a simple explanation can be had, and I'm trying to tell you it all depends wildly on the dozen other variables. And yes, I'm being obstructive, and I apologize for that to a certain extent, and I'm still trying to work through what's even a good approach for EMC questions here. My assessment so far is they're just a terrible fit for this venue.

Comment: Take for example this thread, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/686009/what-is-the-best-practice-when-replacing-a-ribbon-cable-ferrite-clamp-with-chip/686238#686238 it seems simple enough, what's a ferrite bead right? It's even somewhat similar to your question, what's a bead, what's a CMC? You might even find it useful. But see the length. That's the length I personally consider basic enough to introduce and explain the topics in question. Maybe others can be more concise, maybe others are comfortable with less accurate (or indeed erroneous) answers.

Comment: The latter is always a concern, well for anything really, but I've seen plenty of answers here that look good enough to be upvoted but get the technical points completely wrong. Personally, I strive for accurate, representative and responsible answers, and I would be happy to give you an answer here, but it has to be either high enough level that a reasonable length general answer can be given, or specific enough (for X [fully defined project], do Y [specific set of changes]).